# Sql Server - Get Ids of summed rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following table t_vouchers:

```
id  code  amount  isactive
1   a1    10      1
2   a2    20      0
3   a3    30      1
```

I want to compute the sum(amount) of all active vouchers but also get another column containing the list of ids included in this sum. Like below:

```
sum   ids
40    1,3
```

The query would be something like:

```
 select sum(amount) /* ? how to get here the ids stuffed in a comma separated string ? */
 from t_vouchers
 where isactive = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 select sum(amount) sum,
        (
        STUFF((
            SELECT  DISTINCT ',' + CAST(a.id AS VARCHAR(100))
            FROM    t_vouchers a
            WHERE   a.isactive = 1
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'')
        ) ids
 from t_vouchers
 where isactive = 1
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6fcf/1/0)