# mysql - get ids of summed rows

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to get the ids of every row that got summed.  I see there is already an answer for Sql Server, but I need to do this in MYSQL.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Simplified, I have the following table quote_items:

```
id  finishing_sf  finish_id
1   10            1
2   20            2
3   30            1
4   40            2
```

I want to compute the sum of all `finishing_sf` grouped by `finish_id` but also get another column containing the list of ids included in this sum. Like below:

```
finish_id  sum   item_ids
1          40    1,3
2          60    2,4
```

The query would be something like:

```
SELECT SUM(`finishing_sf`) /* (list of IDs) */
FROM `quote_items`
GROUP BY `finish_id`
```

Here's the thread explaining how to do it with Sql-Server-specific syntax.
[Sql Server - Get Ids of summed rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642186/sql-server-get-ids-of-summed-rows)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) here:

```
    SELECT `finish_id`,
           SUM(`finishing_sf`)   AS `sum`,
           GROUP_CONCAT(`id`)    AS `item_ids` 
      FROM `quote_items`
  GROUP BY `finish_id`
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5115/1)

Comment: shouldn't that be `GROUP_CONCAT(id)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

[Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11640438/177920) I used to accomplish something similar